# Cannot execute method when passed as a parameter iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, pointers

I am trying to learn how to pass methods as parameters and then later execute them. In my code I have a method that get's called when clicking a button (last method)  I am trying to pass method1 and method2 to the method placeSlide. I am able to do that but when I try to execute them I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) method1{

}
-(void) method2{

}

-(void) placeSlide: (SEL) meth1 OtherMethod: (SEL) meth2{




    NSTimer *timer1;
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: (1)
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(meth1)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: NO];
    NSTimer *timer2;
    timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: (1.2)
                                             target: self
                                           selector: @selector(meth2)
                                           userInfo: nil
                                            repeats: NO];
}

// get's executed when I click on a btn
-(IBAction) ButtonClick{
    [self placeSlide:@selector(method1) OtherMethod:@selector(method2)];
}
```

and the error that I am getting is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the `SEL` variables as they are.

```
NSTimer *timer1;
timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: (1)
                                         target: self
                                       selector: meth1
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: NO];
NSTimer *timer2;
timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: (1.2)
                                         target: self
                                       selector: meth2
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: NO];
```